# JSON exception when trying to load dictionary inside a class from Firebase Database c#

Tags: c#, json, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

Let's consider a class with a dictionary

```
public class UserProfile
{
public Dictionary<uint, bool> dictionary = new Dictionary<uint, bool>();
//other variables
}
```

Then I add a new field to the dictionary into the database:

```
firebaseClient.Child("users").Child(id + "").Child("dictionary").Child(value + "").PutAsync(true);
```

When I try to read the class from the database (the class was already added before):

```
UserProfile userProfile = await firebaseClient.Child("users").Child(id + "").OnceSingleAsync<UserProfile>()
```

I get an error from Json deserialization.

```
JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.UInt32,System.Boolean]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path 'dictionary', line 1, position 147.
```

What format do I need to use to make this desterilize properly?

Comment: Please update your question to share the exact JSON and a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills Do you mind explaining more what you mean? If you are talking about the JSON file. I can't because it's directly serialized and sent to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is (emphasis mine):

> JsonSerializationException: **Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.UInt32,System.Boolean]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.**
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path 'dictionary', line 1, position 147.

So: you're trying to convert an array in JSON into a Dictionary in C#, and that doesn't work without writing extra code for it.

My guess is that your `id` values are sequential numeric values, which Firebase interprets as array indices. So when you then try to read the data back, you get an array, but your code expects an object.

If that is indeed the cause, the simplest fix is to **not** just use numbers for your keys, but to prefix them with a short alphanumeric value like this:

```
firebaseClient.Child("users").Child("key_"+id).Child("dictionary").Child(value + "").PutAsync(true);
//                                    change here
```

With this change, the keys are all alphanumeric, Firebase will no longer interpret them as an array, and your code will get the `Dictionary` it expects.

---

**Update**: alternatively you can leave your data structure unmodified, but in that case your data structure needs to be an array or `List` as the second half of the error message says.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. The dictionary has uint keys though. I assume changing it to "key_"+id will cause an error since it's a string. 
Is there a way around it to keep it as uint or do I have to change it to string?

Comment: Ah, you can leave your data structure unmodified, but in that case your data structure needs to be an array or `List` as the second half of the error message says.